# how to get the count of a list inside a dictionary

Tags: c#, list, dictionary, count

I have a dictionary of lists and I am trying to get a count of the number of items in each list individually. for example

```
dictionary{

list1: item1, item8

list2: item2, item4, item7

list3: item3, item5, item6

}
```

the code should say list1 contains 2 times list2 contains 3 items and so on

shows me the number lists so 3 in this case this is not what i need:
dic.values.count

also gives me a sum of the total number in the list so 8 in this case:
dic.values.sum(x => x.count)

Comment: Can you please rephrease your question? What is your current result and what is your expectations? Also minimal, working example would help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a [mcve] which shows what you've tried so far. It's not clear what you mean by "the code should say list1 contains 2 times" etc. How would that be represented? This is the sort of thing that a concrete code example would make clearer.

Comment: (It's possible you just want `dic.Values.Select(list => list.Count).ToList()` but we can't tell at the moment.)

Comment: so list1 has 2 times: item1 and item8 this is what i mean look at the list count the number of items in the list and tell me what number you counted to

in the case of my example list1 has 2 items
list 2 has 3 items
list 3 has 3 items

Answer (score 1):

```
String report = String.Join(
    Environment.NewLine, 
    dict.Select( kvp => "List '" + kvp.Key + " has " + kvp.Value.Count.ToString("N0") + " items." )
);
```

Alternatively:

```
String report = String.Join(
    Environment.NewLine, 
    dict.Select( kvp => $"List '{kvp.Key}' has {kvp.Value.Count:N0} items." )
);
```

Comment: This code will not compile in C# because you used the wrong double quotes. The rest however is correct and I will upvote this once this has been edited.

Comment: @Joelius Done. I wrote it on my iPad. It's fixed now.

Comment: Thanks :) I have a quick question though.. Why do you use normal + to concatenate the strings? Don't you think using $ is a cleaner approach if you have more than 2 plus'?

Comment: @Joelius I do agree `$""` strings are cleaner-looking, but you lose control over formatting because it always uses `CurrentCulture` instead of `InvariantCulture` or letting you specify a culture or `IFormatProvider`.

Answer (score 0):

The following code should do the work:

```
// dict is of type Dictionary<string, List<string>>
foreach(KeyValuePair<string, List<string>> entry in dict)
{
    Console.WriteLine("List " + entry.Key + " contains " + entry.Value.Count() + " items");
}
```

Comment: so the main issue with this is that entry.value.count() counts the total number of items not in 1 list so in my example 8 would be displayed...

i was using,
int count = dic.value.count

is there anyway to use your method without the foreach overhead

Comment: @nj645 What do you mean by the "overhead" of `foreach`? There is no real overhead to speak-of.

Comment: @Dai in my basic example there is not really but for my code i have 2 list one with 6000 items and the other with 2000 items i dont want to increment throw all that 1 at a time i want to just be able to say int x = 6000 and if list 1 gains 10 more items x should update to 6010

Comment: @nj645 `Dictionary<K,T>.Values` returns the collections of values in the dictionary, in this case a collection of `List<string>`. Therefore, `Dictionary<K,T>.Values.Count` returns the number of items in that collection, aka, the number of items in the dictionary, i.e. The same as `dict.Count`.